# How do I filter data bi-weekly in SSRS using parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset, ssrs-2012

I want to create a parameter within SSRS for people to filter bi-weekly. I am still looking for a solution to this. I am looking for ideas on how to attack this—either having two parameters that select Week 1 and another parameter that would select Week 2 or creating one parameter that selects 2-week periods.

I have tried something along the lines of this and have had no luck:

=DateAdd("d",7,"01/07/2023")

I have also added a new dataset to filter only to Mondays and then get the weekending date as a new column, "Week_Ending."

Any help/guidance would be excellent.

Comment: Probably need a bit more info. How is the 2 week period defined, would it be 2 weeks from the select date, 2 weeks before the selected date etc.?